# How to retrieve the sheet of power pivot window /model back?

Tags: excel, pivot, powerpivot, powerbi

Data has been imported into power pivot for excel as  tables.These tables are shown in separate sheet in power pivot window.
Created charts and pivot tables from these imported tables.Saved and closed.
Can I retrieve this separate sheet of power pivot window,once I closed the book?

Answer (score 0):

There were excel processes in the task manager.Killed all those process,reopened.Now the Power pivot option is available